# Are maesters always high born?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Are maester's always high born, or is there some other process for applying to be a student?

Samwell Tarly and Aemon Targaryan were definitly high born, but how do others such as Luwin apply if they don't already have a high born level of education?